# running perl file as other user to modify directory with root permission 755

Tags: perl, redhat

I have a perl file that I am executing as other user(Rajesh).
That is trying to write a file into a directory which is owned by root and has 755 as directory permission. There are other directories also but I don't want user(Rajesh) to write into them only that particular directory.

How can I achieve this without modifying directory permission to 777.
I am free to modify /etc/sudoers.
Other suggestions are welcome(I am using red-hat 6)

Regards,
Kuwarbi

Comment: Why don't you change the directory permissions to 775, then change the group owner to, let's say "somegroup", then add your user to that group?

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue about changing the directory's permission? What about changing ownership, so user rajesh`owns that particular directory? Even if the directory was owned by`rajesh`, user`root` would also have write permissions.

Is this a directory like `/usr/bin` or `/etc` that is normally owned by `root`? In that case, I wouldn't want any user writing to those particular directories at all.

What about adding user `rajesh` to a group, and then set the group ownership of that directory to the group you put `rajesh` in, and then changing the permissions to `775`. User `rajash` could write to that directory, but still not write to other directories owned by root.

Comment: yes the directory is under /etc/ and I have to give other user(rajesh) to write permission for that particular directory. I can't create any group.

Comment: @user3007526 Why are you able to modify `/etc/sudoers` but unable to create a group? Regardless, as David said, you probably don't want random users writing to system directories anyway. What directory are you trying to write to and what exactly are you trying to do?